# Prove the inequality without using the concept of Arithmetic and Geometric mean inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

$\displaystyle ( 2m+1) r^{m}( 1-r) < 1-r^{2m+1}$
where $r<1$ and m is positive integer.
I can prove it by concept of arithmetic and geometric mean inequality.
But I am curious to know whether there is any other method to prove it as in the book nothing has been mentioned about arithmetic-geometric mean inequality throughout the chapter Geometric progression (Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight).Can this be solved only by theorem of summation of series etc.

Comment: I presume you want $r>0$ as well as $r<1$?

Comment: Yes you are right r>0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $0<r<1$,
$$\frac{1-r^{2m+1}}{r^m(1-r)}=\frac{1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{2m}}{r^m}
=\frac1{r^m}+\frac1{r^{m-1}}+\cdots+\frac1r+1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^m.$$
If you can prove that $1/r^k+r^k>2$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,m$ then this will be $>2m+1$.

Comment: Truly elegant...

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda That's down to Hall & Knight of course.

Comment: I was writing an answer by induction... but seeing your answer I couldnt continue lol... Great one